# rMaps/Leaflet : same coordinate plot different location

Tags: r, leaflet, rcharts

I was trying out rMaps package, which uses leaflet js api. While plotting a coordinate `c(3.09407,101.504961)`, rmaps/leaflet point is off from the actual point.

```
require(rMaps)
map <- Leaflet$new()  
map$setView( c(3.09407,101.504961))   
map$marker(c(3.09407,101.504961))     
map
```

Open Street Map

[image: Open Street Map]
Google MAp

[image: Google Map]

rMap/Leaflet plot

[image: rMap plot]

is this a known issue? Does leaflet requires some correction to get exact plot.

Comment: it seems in the html source with rMap generated, maker value is 3.0941,101.5 . which is wrong. Any one has any solution for this issue?

Comment: It is a bug in rMaps, and NOT Leaflet. It happens due to rounding when converting to JSON. There is a pull request with a fix, which I will be merging shortly.